# Usar elementos de mi Adapter

Tags: android, recyclerview, color, adapter

Hola amigos estoy trabajando en llenar una recyclerview esto lo hago usando volley consumiendo un servicio rest hasta aqui todo bien, pero tengo que cambiar el color del cardview dependiendo un dato que me es mandado desde el servicio. Como puedo realizar esto amigos?

Adjunto codigo:

Adapter

```
public class OrdenesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<OrdenesAdapter.OrdenesViewHolder> {

private OnItemClickListener mlistener;
ArrayList<Ordenes> ordenesArrayList;


public interface OnItemClickListener{
    void onItemClick(int position);
}
List<Ordenes> listaOrdenes;

public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener){
    mlistener = listener;
}

public OrdenesAdapter(List<Ordenes> listaOrdenes){
    this.listaOrdenes = listaOrdenes;
    this.ordenesArrayList = new ArrayList<Ordenes>();
    this.ordenesArrayList.addAll(listaOrdenes);
}


@Override
public OrdenesViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View vista = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_asignadas, parent, false);
    RecyclerView.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    vista.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    return new OrdenesViewHolder(vista);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(OrdenesViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.textCompanyResumenOrdenes.setText(listaOrdenes.get(position).getCompany().toString());
    holder.textNoOrdenResumenOrdenes.setText(listaOrdenes.get(position).getCounter().toString());
    holder.textTimeResumenOrdenes.setText(listaOrdenes.get(position).getStreet_destino().toString());
    holder.textCobroResumen.setText(listaOrdenes.get(position).getAmount().toString());
    holder.textMinAproxResumen.setText(listaOrdenes.get(position).getCreated().toString());
}



@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listaOrdenes.size();
}

public class OrdenesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView textCompanyResumenOrdenes, textNoOrdenResumenOrdenes, textTimeResumenOrdenes, textCobroResumen, textMinAproxResumen, textTimeTrascurridoResumen;

    public OrdenesViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textCompanyResumenOrdenes = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textCompanyResumenOrdenes);
        textNoOrdenResumenOrdenes = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textNoOrdenResumenOrdenes);
        textTimeResumenOrdenes = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textTimeResumenOrdenes);
        textCobroResumen = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textCobroResumen);
        textMinAproxResumen = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textMinAproxResumen);
        textTimeTrascurridoResumen = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textTimeTrascurridoResumen);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mlistener != null) {
                    int position = getAdapterPosition();
                    if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                        mlistener.onItemClick(position);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

public void setFilter (String counter){
    counter = counter.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
    listaOrdenes.clear();
    if (counter.length() == 0){
        listaOrdenes.addAll(ordenesArrayList);
    }else {
        for(Ordenes PL : ordenesArrayList){
            if(PL.getCounter().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(counter)){
                listaOrdenes.add(PL);
            }
        }
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}

Preparo la lista

```
 listaOrdenes = new ArrayList<>();
    thiscontext = container.getContext();
    recyclerOrdenes = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerOrdenesResumen);
```

Lleno la lista con los datos optemidos

```
adapter = new OrdenesAdapter(listaOrdenes);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                recyclerOrdenes.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Resultado:

Cada cardview debe de cambiar de color de acuerdo a unos datos que son enviados

[image]

De antemano gracias =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En `onBindViewHolder` obten un string, por ejemplo:

```
String clave = listaOrdenes.get(position).getCompany().toString();
```

Luego comparas, si coincide aplicas el color al cardView:

```
if (clave.equals("Company 1")){
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFDF618C"));
            //puede ser necesario cambiar el fondo de los textViews:
            holder.textNoOrdenResumenOrdenes.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFDF618C"));  // color rojo
            holder.textTimeResumenOrdenes.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFDF618C"));
        } else if (clave...
```